# Show that the singularity is removable or a pole of order m

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D(z_0,r) \backslash \{z_0\} \rightarrow {\bf C}$ be holomorphic on a disk $D(z_0,r)$ except for a singularity at $z_0$. Let $m$ be an integer, and suppose that there exist $C>0, \varepsilon>0$ such that one has the upper bound $\displaystyle  |f(z)| \leq C |z-z_0|^{-m-1+\varepsilon}$ for all $z \in D(z_0,r) \backslash \{z_0\}$. Show that the singularity of $f$ at $z_0$ is either removable, or a pole of order at most $m$. In particular, if one has
$\displaystyle |f(z)| \leq C |z-z_0|^{-1+\varepsilon}$ for all $z \in D(z_0,r) \backslash \{z_0\}$, then the singularity is removable.

The hint suggests to use the laurent expansion for $f(z)=\sum_0^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n+\sum_{-1}^{-\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$, and a limiting argument to evaluate the Laurent coefficients $a_n$ for $n \leq -1$.

I tried to use the Riemann's theorem for removable singularities but that requires that $f(z)$ be bounded, however $f(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to z_0$.

Comment: take $g(z)=(z-z_0)^{m+1}f(z)$

Comment: How do I proceed after that @Conrad?

Comment: $g$ is bounded at $z_0$ (and actually has a zero there because of the $\epsilon$ in the estimate power) so the singularity is removable, $g$ is analytic and actually $g(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)$ etc

Comment: I understand tha g(z) is bounded. But we are considering the function f(z). and require to show that the singularity is removable or has a pole of order atmost m. How does proving g(z) is bounded show that f(z) has a removable singularity or pole of order m? @Conrad

Comment: as noted $g(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)$ with $g,h$ analytic (removable singularity plus zero) so $f=h/(z-z_0)^m$, hence by definition $f$ has a pole of order at most $m$, done

Comment: Thank you @Conrad